# MySQL Trigger, Same variable / timestamp across each row

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use triggers to create an automated audit trail.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `audit_trigger_name_here` AFTER UPDATE ON `source_table`
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO `audit_table` (`OldCol`, `NewCol`, `TimeStamp`)
    VALUES (OLD.Col, NEW.Col, UTC_TIMESTAMP())
```

So far so good.  But since a single query can change multiple rows we want to be able to group them with a unique identifier.

I attempted to do this with UTC_TIMESTAMP(), but expect this to result in a new timestamp each iteration of the "FOR EACH ROW."  What I need instead is a way to set the timestamp in a variable once at the beginning, before the FOR EACH ROW part, and then be able to use that variable.

I'm very new to mysql, so I'd appreciate specifics in your response.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is a column in your source_table that is updated with a current utc_timestamp every time you update it (not in the trigger) then use that in the trigger.

You'll find all values in OLD/NEW. namespace and if all rows just get the same utc_timestamp so will all insert in the audit table.

Along the lines of

```
create table source (
  id int,
  value varchar(255),
  ts timestamp
);

create trigger audit after update on source
for each row
insert into audit (old, new, ts) values (old.value, new.value, new.ts);

update source 
   set value = 'some new value', 
       ts    = utc_timestamp() 
 where id in (1,2,3);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Won't that cause the utc_timestamps to be inited with slightly different values since each row is created individually though?

Comment: It depends on how you update the rows in the source table. If you update multiple rows at once then you'll also set their value to the same utc_timestamp.